# How to prove $x_1 + x_2 +\ldots+x_n \le \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Rightarrow (1 - x_1)(1-x_2)\cdot \ldots \cdot(1-x_n)\ge \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

Prove, that $x_1 + x_2 +\ldots+x_n \le \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Rightarrow (1 -
 x_1)(1-x_2)\cdot \ldots \cdot(1-x_n)\ge \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$. Value $n$ is a positive real number $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$

I tried using mathematical induction but didn't get too far with that. Any ideas how to solve it with induction?

Comment: "Value $n$ is a positive real number ..." did you mean to write that all $x_i, i=1..n$ are positive real numbers?

Comment: @rtybase Yes. The base number aka $n$ is a positive real number.

Comment: Put conditions on the $x_i$ because it is obviously false, for instance, with $x_i\lt -1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for the induction step: $$1-(x_n + x_{n+1}) \le (1-x_n)(1-x_{n+1})$$
for $x_n, x_{n+1} \ge 0$.